# Independent Variable groups w/ n=1 possible for Kruskal Wallis?

Tags: kruskal-wallis-test

I am working with clinical data with 7 groups that constitute my independent variable and a not normally distributed dependent variable. I know I have to use KW test to check for significant differences between my groups. The problem is that 3 of the 7 groups have an n=1.

I know KW is not as sensitive to unequal sample sizes as parametric tests but is n=1 even possible? Would I be violating one of the assumptions (same overall dist. of data between groups) if I  run KW?

I cannot combine the values of the 3 groups as each group is very different from the other. I also don't know if its possible to remove these 3 groups for the KW test as I would be misrepresenting the reality of things

Please let me know what you think. Thank you.

Comment: KW does not assume the same distribution in each group. It is simply a test for stochastic dominance.

Comment: What do you mean by "I also don't know if its possible to remove these 3 groups for the KW test as I would be misrepresenting the reality of things" Isn't *the reality of things* that you do not have enough data to make any statistical claims about these three groups?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question... I don't know if a n=1 is ever a good place to start for your analysis, even for KW test. Perhaps just try to get more samples for those groups?